# How to close a Modal Popup via Javascript code within Chrome Browser Developer Console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, jquery-events

How to close a Modal Popup via Javascript code within the Chrome 'Developer' console window?

I'm unable to close the following modal popup listed below with the following code when entered within the chrome browser developer console textfield:

Attempted to close the modal popup with the following code:

```
$(".modal-dialog.close").close();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That depends on how the site works.  But you could try calling `click()` on an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try triggering the click event on the close button:

```
$(".close").trigger("click");
```